# Collect messages

Tags: ros, callback, rospy, topics, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to collect messages from a topic, that is, subscribe to a topic, and then do something with some condition about the message is met (a flag on the message) with **all** the messages recibed previously. Since the callbacks are functions (and well-made functions should't have state), I don't see a straightforward way to do this. So, what can I do?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172684/collect-messages/) by [crpizarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9346/crpizarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're gonna have to collect your messages somehow, e.g. in a class that has the callback.

ROS provides a cache that does this by time: http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Cache A simple deque might also be sufficient.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crpizarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9346/crpizarr/) on 2014-06-03**:
In the end I used a class to collect the messages. Thanks